# Restangular data sent is being splitted

Tags: angularjs, restangular

```
    Restangular.one('suppliers', 'me').getList('websites').then(
        (data) ->
            $scope.websites = data
            $scope.websites.patch()
    )
```

I'm just trying this for a quick test.

So the api call on /suppliers/me/websites returns an array but when I try to patch from the Restangular object it sends the data splitted as you can see below.

```
    [{"0":"h","1":"t","2":"t","3":"p","4":":","5":"/","6":"/","7":"w","8":"w","9":"w","10":".","11":"p","12":"f","13":"c","14":"o","15":"n","16":"c","17":"e","18":"p","19":"t","20":".","21":"c","22":"o","23":"m"}]
```

I'm new to Angular & Restangular , what am I missing ?

Edit : To be clear, I insta patch for the test but normally I modify the websites array by adding / removing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you're returning a string from your service, whereas a valid JSON response is expected by Restangular.

For example:

```
[{"website": "http://www.example.com"}, {"website": "http://www.domain.com"}]
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that in your question, you say your service returns an array. Double-check what it does return and make sure that it is [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/).

**EDIT 2:** It seems that Restangular expects not only valid JSON, but also JSON formatted as my code sample above is (ie. `[{"key": "value"}]` and not `["value"]`.

Comment: As I use getList the response has to be an array. I'm using FOSRestBundle and the raw response is `["http:\/\/www.pfconcept.com"]` which is a valid json array. Also if I run a foreach on $scope.websites I can see that the data is OK.

Comment: In [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gamZAL4EZCOfL8LymmF6?p=preview), using `[{"key": "value"}]` (an array of key/value pairs) results in a PATCH with a request payload, whereas `["value"]` results in a PATCH with an empty array. The latter may be valid JSON technically, but I don't think it's what Restangular is looking for.

Comment: Yes I just changed the api side by returing an array of objects instead of an array of strings (raw response : `[{"url":"http:\/\/www.pfconcept.com"}]`) and it's working